# Qt Designer doesn't appear to add custom slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to connect a button's clicked event to a custom slot. I've added this slot to the main QWidget in Qt Designer, and connected the button's emit signal to it. However, when running the project I get the following output, and clicking the button does nothing:

```
/home/nisse/Code/SimpleQtApp/cmake-build-debug/SimpleQtApp
QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::changeLabel() in /home/nisse/Code/SimpleQtApp/cmake-build-debug/SimpleQtApp_autogen/include/ui_labelwindow.h:71
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'labelwindow')
```

Another button's signal connected to a label's clear slot works fine.

Manually adding a method to `public slots:` in the widget's header file doesn't fix this problem either.

Any clues on how to fix this? I'm working in CLion with QT5.

Edit:
The .ui file ends with this content:

```
 <slots>
  <slot>changeLabel()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

changeLabel is the slot I defined.

Edit 2: using QT Creator to create the project, pasting in the UI and then opening that project in CLion causes everything to work correctly. I've compared the ui files and they're identical. My best guess would be that it's something to do with the CMake file. I'm very new to all of that so I'm not sure what's going on, but I suppose my issue is resolved.

Comment: Did you check the ui file? The slot name should be there

Comment: Edit - looks like I can't do syntax highlighting. I'll add the end contents of the file to my question.

Comment: It looks like your target object is a `QWidget`. Did you correclty set the placeholder widget class for it in the designer?

Comment: I am not aware of what a placeholder widget is. I thought QWidget has to be the main class? (it's the main window)

Comment: Need to create a subclass of QWidget that has the additional slot, then you can connect to it.